# What applications require 1GB pages?

Tags: memory, memory-management, computer-science, virtual-memory

X86 and x64 processors allow for 1GB pages when the PDPE flag is set on the cpu. In what application would this be practical or required and for what reason?

Comment: It's hard to imagine any application where it might be *required*. *Beneficial* is probably a better term - and applies where 1) a 1GB page is entirely full, or nearly so, reducing wasted space, and 2) there is heavy churn in page tables and TLB entries - larger pages means less entries required per GB of memory, and thus reduces pressure on the virtual memory hardware/software.

Comment: It just seems like an exceptional size for rare situations. Upon research I can not find anything that requires such a large page size considering the majority of page sizes are 4096 bytes (by default at least).

Answer (score 4):

Hugepage would help in cases where you have a large memory footprint and memory access pattern spans large distance (across 4K pages).

It not only reduces TLB miss but also saves OS mm system page tables size.

A very good example is packet processing. In high throughput network applications (1Gbps or more), packets are normally stored in a packet buffer pool (i.e. pooling technique). For example, every packet buffer is 2KB in size and the pool contains 512 buffers. Access pattern of this packet buffer pool might not be sequential (buffer indexed at 1,2,3,4,5...) but rather random over time (1,104,407,45,905...). Since normal page size is 4K, normal TLB won't help here since each packet access would incur a TLB miss and there is a lot of different buffers sitting on different pages.

In contrast, if you put the pool in a 1GB hugepage, then all packet buffers share the same hugepageTLB entry thus avoiding misses.

This is used in DPDK (Data Plane Development Kit) where the packet
rate is very high that cycles wasted on TLB miss is not negligible.

> Hugepage support is required for the large memory pool allocation used
> for packet buffers (the HUGETLBFS option must be enabled in the
> running kernel as indicated the previous section). By using hugepage
> allocations, performance is increased since fewer pages are needed,
> and therefore less Translation Lookaside Buffers (TLBs, high speed
> translation caches), which reduce the time it takes to translate a
> virtual page address to a physical page address. Without hugepages,
> high TLB miss rates would occur with the standard 4k page size,
> slowing performance.

http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html#bios-setting-prerequisite-on-x86

Another example from Oracle:

> ...almost 6.8 GB of memory used for page tables when hugepages were not
> configured...
>
> ...after hugepages were allocated and used by the Oracle database. The page table overhead was reduced to slightly less than 23 MB

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/understanding-hugepages-in-oracle-database.html

Related links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

--Edit--

However, hugepage should be used carefully. Above I mentioned that memory pool would benefit from 1GB hugepage. However, if you have an access pattern even across 1GB page boundary, then it might not help. There is an excellent blog on this:

http://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2014/02/18/how-bad-can-1gb-pages-be/

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an application that uses huge amounts of memory—Molecular modeling. Weather prediction—especially if it has no user interaction.

Large pages:

(1) reduce the amount of page table overhead memory
(2) increases the amount of memory that can be stored in the MMU cache. (The same number of cache entries references more memory).

Answer (score 0):

I have LabView installed on my Dell ws with 8 cores and 16GB DDRM, driving 4 24" monitors.
If I create a video processor or compositor of most any type, with a 1024px x 1024px 'drawing' display, LabView reserves 1.5GB before I even began to composite. It was built from C and C++.
 I often store image details in 3D arrays of 256 x 256 x 256 of U32 integers that hold each RGB pixel color, plus the alpha channel for opacity or masking. That's 64MB per each layer of buffered video. If I need to remember 128 layers, thats 8GB right there.
 LabView is a programming langauge structured much like a CAD program. If I need 8GB for a series of video (HDTV) buffers, that is what it will give me, with a few seconds wait for malloc to do its work.
 If I created a 8GB 3D array for a database, it would be no different, even if I did it in MySQL (not as an array). To me, having many gigabytes of ram to play with is the norm, not an exception.